# Inkscape: Text appears upside down without any "on path" business

Tags: inkscape

[image: sample Inkscape png]

I'm new to Inkscape and haven't tried anything even remotely advanced like putting text on paths. For some reason, Unicode mode in text (ctr + U) didn't work so I stopped trying. But since then text always appears upside down. Google search only leads to "upside down text *on path*" related links. The only way to get text upright is to flip the text object vertically. Please help me resolve this.

**Edit**: It only happens when I drag a pdf and drop it on the Inkscape icon to open Inkscape with that pdf.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This is difficult to answer without access to the PDF. Can you share it?  What software was the PDF made with? Is the PDF OK when viewed with Adobe Reader?  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/144120/edit) and add details. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank you. Sure, I'll edit the question, only I'm not sure how to attach a pdf. The pdf is alright when viewed with Adobe Reader. A code I use called phonopy generated this pdf using matplotlib in python.

Comment: You'd need to share it using a file sharing service, such as microsoft's OneDrive, then you can post the link here.